# How can I prevent QUERY from printing its calculation to two rows, and not have it print "sum"?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, indexing, sum, google-query-language

I've created a Google Sheets function, with the intended effect of getting the sum of numeric values between two dates, where the value in a different column is equal to a string. The calculation however is having unintended side-effects.

The problem is that the function starts out by returning the string value ***"sum"*** to the cell, before returning the ***actual*** result of the calculation onto a second row.

How can I limit the QUERY function in Google Sheets to ***only*** return the value of the calculation I'm querying for?

```
=QUERY('Finance, raw data'!A2:D;"SELECT SUM(C) WHERE D='Audible' AND A >= date '2021-08-01' AND A < date '2021-09-01'")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

label it:

```
=QUERY('Finance, raw data'!A2:D;
 "select sum(C) 
  where D  ='Audible' 
    and A >= date '2021-08-01' 
    and A <  date '2021-09-01'
  label sum(C)''")
```

offset it:

```
=QUERY(QUERY('Finance, raw data'!A2:D;
 "select sum(C) 
  where D  ='Audible' 
    and A >= date '2021-08-01' 
    and A <  date '2021-09-01'"); 
 "offset 1"; 0)
```

index it:

```
=INDEX(QUERY('Finance, raw data'!A2:D;
 "select sum(C) 
  where D  ='Audible' 
    and A >= date '2021-08-01' 
    and A <  date '2021-09-01'
  label sum(C)''"); 2)
```

Comment: But this is not a solution to index what you want, the question is how to sum the two lines that the query are not able to do it exactly.
Index with value 1 or 2 will only ignore the other term. this is why this is not a solution.
Im facing the same issue since 1 week and never found the issue why the Query is returning two rows even im using the Sum(Col1) and the Group by argument.

Comment: @AhmedMihoub happy to craft you solution if you share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result